# Android Database in my own directory

Tags: android, database, sqlite, directory

I'm trying to use my own database in an Android application.   Most all the topics and tutorials on this topic suggest that you can create it and open it using `SQLiteOpenHelper`, which by default use `data/data/com.my.application/databases` folder.  I've seen the recommendation to copy the file from `context.getAssets.open(dbname)` to the default sqlite path.  If this is in fact the solution, what is the right path to pass my `database.db` file?

Comment: so do you want to know which path? destination?

Comment: yeah thats the case.. i thought i had to put the database file in the "assets" folder of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my friend you can try this one code

```
/**
 * 
 * Purpose: Open and Read database to fetch records from different database
 * tables.
 * 
 * @version 1.0
 * 
 * @author ketan kalariya(ketan.kalariya@indianic.com) 
 *        
 * **/

    public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private Context myContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
        // Comman KEYs of tables
        public static String MASTERFENCE_TABLE = "MasterFence";
        public static String KEY_ID = "_id";
        public static String AREA = "area";
        public static String TAG = "tag";
        public static String TITLE = "title";
        public static String DESCR = "description";
        public static String NO = "no";

        public static String ADDFENCEPOINT_TABLE = "AddFencePoint";
        public static String ADDLATLONG_TABLE = "AddLatLong";
        public static String LAT = "lat";
        public static String LONG = "long";

        public static String TEMPFENCEPOINT_TABLE = "TempFencePoint";
        public static String TEMPLATLONG_TABLE = "TempLatLong";

        public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.dbname), null,
                    1);
            this.myContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }

        // ---Create the database---
        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

            // ---Check whether database is already created or not---
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if (!dbExist) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try {
                    // ---If not created then copy the database---
                    copyDataBase();
                    this.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }
            }
        }

        // --- Check whether database already created or not---
        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            try {
                final String myPath = "/data/data/" + myContext.getPackageName()
                        + "/databases/" + myContext.getString(R.string.dbname);
                final File f = new File(myPath);
                if (f.exists())
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }

        // --- Copy the database to the output stream---
        public void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

            final InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(
                    myContext.getString(R.string.dbname));

            final String outFileName = "/data/data/" + myContext.getPackageName()
                    + "/databases/" + myContext.getString(R.string.dbname);

            final OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }

        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

            // --- Open the database---
            final String myPath = "/data/data/" + myContext.getPackageName()
                    + "/databases/" + myContext.getString(R.string.dbname);

            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }

        /**
         * Close the database
         */
        public synchronized void closeDatabase() {
            if (myDataBase != null)
                ;
            myDataBase.close();
            SQLiteDatabase.releaseMemory();
            super.close();
        }


        /** This method is insert require detail in database table. **/
        public long insertMasterFence(String area, String title, String descr,
                String tag) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(AREA, area);
            values.put(TITLE, title);
            values.put(DESCR, descr);
            values.put(TAG, tag);
            Log.v("  db ", area + " " + title + " " + " " + descr + " " + tag);
            return myDataBase.insert(MASTERFENCE_TABLE, null, values);

        }
```

Comment: drop the `extends SQLiteOpenHelper` part if you don't use the `onCreate` / `onUpgrade` mechanism. Although it might work if you use it correctly it can give you a lot  of errors because if you get your db via `.getWritableDatabase` it might give you an empty database (since there is no code in onCreate